# Javascript await object property to be set

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, async-await

```
getStore().then((store) => {
  buildRates().then((rates) => {
    let newStore = store;
    newStore.rates = rates;
    setStore(newStore).then((res) => {
      // callback
      cb(null, res);
    })
  })
});
```

Having trouble writing this in async/await syntax. When I try to write with awaits like this ...

```
let store = await getStore();
store.rates = await buildRates();
setStore(store).then((res) => {
  // callback
  cb(null, res);
});
```

... `setStore` uses the original object returned from `await getStore()`, without an object on `store.rates` from `await buildRates()`

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://jsfiddle.net/kb51h92y/

Comment: I assume that `buildRates` does no longer return a Promise, or that the promise is resolved with a value you do not expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The issue was `buildRates()` not being a proper promises, oops!

Comment: So, the problem was in code you do not show.  I'd suggest you just delete this question then because its of no use to anyone else as a future reference going forward.

Comment: can't delete sry :S